# How to make Intel Turbo Boost to reach its maximum for testing cooling efficiency?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, turbo-boost, stress-test

I noticed that Intel stock cooler occasionally gets really loud (oh, Intel, why did you make your stock coolers worse; SandyBridge ones were larger and quieter), so I will replace it with a third party silent cooler (no overclocking - I have non-K CPU).

But to find out whether my new cooler and thermal paste is doing its job well, I wanted to capture temperature benchmarks before and after cooler replacement.

I thought - well, I can run a benchmark tool (Cinebench or WinRar built in benchmark) and this would make my CPU work hard and reach its highest temperatures, right? **Wrong!!!**

When I did that, HWMonitor utility showed that although all CPU cores are 100% loaded, still the CPU hasn't reached its highest frequency and max temperature recorded in HWMonitor history, and also the stock fan was not spinning at full speed and it was pretty quiet. Here's a proof:

[image: HWmonitor capture while running Cinebench]

As you can see, all cores are 100% loaded, turbo boost has kicked in (but not fully - only up to 4000 MHz and not max 4200 value) and temperatures are below recorded max 75 C.

**Why so?** Because of how Intel's Turbo Boost works. It won't kick in when all cores are 100% loaded; it works at max for one core only (at least, that's what people in forums say; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

So, I thought I could load only one core. WinRar and Cinebench both have single core test modes. But it did not work - it just disables multithreading and lets OS distribute the load across all the CPU cores, and thus all CPU cores are loaded partially and none of them is 100% loaded.

Then I tried to adjust Affinity setting in Task Manager - that was kinda success and one of the cores was 100% loaded... but still turbo boost did not kick in fully - no 4.2GHz and fan not spinning at its max.

Still, when randomly launching and closing various programs, I see occasional CPU core frequency jumps to 4.2 GHz and accordingly temperature rises and the fan spins faster and louder.

The question is:

**How do I force the Turbo Boost to its max to stress test my cooling? Is there any tool which can do that?** Of course, I would like to do it safely, just within normal working limits; no overclocking etc.

Comment: I don't think you can. The whole point of the adaptive power and thermal management systems is to prevent software from pushing the hardware into damaging situations, while still providing the maximum safe performance possible. I'd try Prime95, but your fan won't speed up unless your temp is still going up, and the system will adjust the clock multiplier as it sees fit. Also consider that there are multiple factors that affect temp, and your room temp is a surprisingly large one. there is no gaurentee that your max temp and max freq occurred during the same event.